# Field Slideshow Different Trasitions Effects on Different Pages

Tags: javascript

Is there a way we can define different transition effects on different pages for field slide show.

-- ok here is an edit

field_slideshow calls a jquey file field_slideshow.js in the header of the page. It has this code which I think controls the animation effects.

fx: settings.fx

Is it possible to override this line only on particular page to define different animation effect.

I am thinking to insert some override code before closing body through [JS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector)

Comment: This seems like it would be better as a support request/feature request in the module's issue queue...

Comment: already did that :)

Comment: In that case, please provide a link to the issue.  The issue may get solved/implemented on drupal.org and future readers to this site will not easily find it if there is no link.

Comment: here is the link https://drupal.org/node/1938012